# Sort week and year in descending order

Tags: php, mysql

in my table (mysql table) there is a field "week_year". This field having data like:

```
WK52_2014
WK51_2014
WK50_2014
WK09_2015
WK08_2015
WK07_2015
WK06_2015
WK05_2015
WK04_2015
WK03_2015
WK02_2015
WK01_2015
```

Here "WK52_2014" means 52nd week of 2014. if i query like below

```
$query="SELECT DISTINCT(week_year) AS week_year FROM `table1` order by week_year desc";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($noticia = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $noticia['week_year'] . "\n";
}
```

it will echo as mentioned above. but for me i want it to display current week on top (WK09_2015) then previous week (wk08_2015), then WK07_2015 as mentioned below.

```
WK09_2015
WK08_2015
WK07_2015
WK06_2015
WK05_2015
WK04_2015
WK03_2015
WK02_2015
WK01_2015
WK52_2014
WK51_2014
WK50_2014
```

Could you please help me how can i go ahead.

Thanks in advance,

Br,
Mahadeva

Comment: What is the specific problem you encounter? Please be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store those strings, instead compute them from a DATE field.  Here's a clue on how to construct your strings, using NOW() as an example:

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT('WK', RIGHT(CONCAT('0', WEEK(now())), 2), '_', YEAR(now()));
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CONCAT('WK', RIGHT(CONCAT('0', WEEK(now())), 2), '_', YEAR(now())) |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| WK08_2015                                                          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. your command will display only WK08_2015. also i want to display all weeks for 2015 and 2014 also as i mention current week on top followed by previous weeks

Comment: @MAHADEVASWAMYHN swap the call to `now()` to be the date column on your table, you can then `ORDER BY YEAR([column]), WEEK([column])` as required

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mySql [`substring`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) function to order by the year portion of your `week_year` field like this:

```
order by SUBSTRING(week_year,6) desc, week_year desc
```